# Error en rails Object doesn't support #inspect con nombre de tabla con palabra reservada en mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

El nombre de la tabla es "char" la cual es una palabra reservada en mysql, como puedo corregir edte error sin tener que cambiar el nombre de la tabla?

**no puedo cambiar el nombre de la tabla porque es del juego ragnarok**

En el modelo (Character.rb)

```
self.table_name = "char"
```

En la consola

```
d = Character.all
Character Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `char`.* FROM `char`
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
```

En index.html.erb

```
undefined method `define_attribute_methods' for 0:Fixnum
```

Comment: probaste haciendo el query directo en la consola mysql? `SELECT \`char\`.* FROM \`char\``